# Using generator to create a masking function for a dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, generator

I have a lengthy dataframe comprised of 5 indicator variables.  Each row will sum to 3 (i.e. 3 indicated characteristics will be present).  I would like to iterate through the dataframe and mask n variables (i.e. 1 or 2 indicators get flipped from 1 to 0) at random for all rows.

If my input table is structured as follows:

```
index ind01 ind02 ind03 ind04 ind05
    0     0     1     0     1     1
    1     1     0     1     0     1
    2     0     1     1     0     1
    3     0     0     1     1     1
    4     1     1     1     0     0
    5     0     1     0     1     1
```

If my function is passed n as an input, it would then pull a draw of n items from the 3 columns with non-zero values in that row, and then the dataframe will be re-written to leave (3-n) non-zero indicator values.

Given the regularity of the pattern, is this a problem that a generator could be utilized to optimize the minimum number of calculations?  E.g. flatten the columns into an np array.  Then iterate over them with a generator flipping n out of 3 array elements.  And then reshape back to the original form at the end?

I can write the loop text for this.  But I'm intrigued by generators and how they can be utilized to speed up code (and unfamiliar if they can carry "memory items" that would facilitate this type of solution).

Comment: `generators` really only save time and memory if they replace a chain of list operations.  They have little value in `numpy` code, and probably not `pandas` (though I have studied your case).

Answer (score 1):

Generators can help you to keep memory use low, by not materializing lists, but instead only yielding one element at a time. However, they'll do nothing for performance, and working essentially like a normal for-loop (or even slower, since each new element is effectively a function call).

If you want performance with this kind of task: use numpy directly. It sounds like you want something like `np.random.choice` that will take values at C-speed without python call overhead or the need to create python objects for every entry.